# How do I set the style of SVG CSS attributes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, css-transitions, svg-animate

I'm trying to dynamically determine the length of an array of SVG paths and then insert this value into the HTML DOM style object for the attributes `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset`.

```
var horizontals = document.getElementsByClassName('hLine');
for (var i = 0; i < horizontals.length; i++ ) {
    var drawingComponent = horizontals[i],
        length = svgPiece.getTotalLength();

    horizontals[i].style.strokeDasharray = length;
    horizontals[i].style.strokeDashoffset = length;
}
```

In the example found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/orvn/s9KaW/6/), all the `.hLine` paths (all the horizontal lines) should animate, but they do not.
Is this because `strokeDasharray` and `strokeDashoffset` aren't supported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a start, there are some things wrong with that Javascript:

```
var horizontals = document.getElementsByClassName('hLine');
```

Your SVG doesn't have any elements with the class 'hLine'.

```
length = svgPiece.getTotalLength();
```

'svgPiece' is not defined anywhere.

Try something like this:

```
var horizontals = document.querySelectorAll('#horizontal path')

for (var i = 0; i < horizontals.length; i++ ) {
    var path = horizontals[i],
        length = path.getTotalLength();

    path.style.strokeDasharray = length;
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = length; 
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/s9KaW/7/) - although there is still some work to do to get the animation working properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can always also just fix the path length by setting pathLength (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength) to a value (like 100 for easy percent-based modification).